# How to get binded observable content inside a click function of a button?

Tags: knockout.js

Well I been facing a tricky case here but to make things simpler for everyone's understanding let me explain my scenario .

I have two buttons inside a loop with respective bindings `text:name1` and `text:name2` with click binding .

**ViewModel:**

```
           var viewModel = function(){
                var self=this;
                self.arr=ko.observableArray([1]);
                self.name1=ko.observable("click1");
                self.name2=ko.observable("click2");
                self.clickme=function(){
                    console.log(this)
               // this.name1('yoo') this.name1 or name2 should be dynamic based on btn click
               //Here how to access the observanle binded to 'text' for the clicked button
                }
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

When a button is clicked , is there any way i can get the clicked buttons `text binded observable` inside my click function i.e i need `name1` inside my function if button1 clicked .

I tried `$element`, `$context` passing as parameter to a function to VM but doesn't solve it.

Demo fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/23135/)**

Any help or idea on this would be great .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass them in to the function.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:arr">
    <button data-bind="text:$root.name1,click:function(){$root.clickme($root.name1)}"></button>
    <button data-bind="text:$root.name2,click:function(){$root.clickme($root.name2)}"></button>
</div>
```

Then handle them inside your view model like this:

```
self.clickme = function (val) {
    alert(val());
}
```

Here is a [modified version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3t6r6sds/)